# How to do feature selection on SparseMatrix matrix in R

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, feature-selection, fselector

I have text classification problem with over 20k features, 3m objects, and over 3k classes. Data is very sparse.
I wrote the program on R.
Data matrix in sparseMatrix object.
How can I select features on this data?
I found package FSelector, but it is not working with sparseMatrix, only data.frame, and I can not convert data due to memory limitation.

Comment: 3k is a very big number for classification. What do you use? some hierarchical classification?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at:

FSelector:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/FSelector/FSelector.pdf

varSelRF:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/varSelRF/varSelRF.pdf

R, correlation matrix filters, PCA & backward selection:

http://www.r-bloggers.com/introduction-to-feature-selection-for-bioinformaticians-using-r-correlation-matrix-filters-pca-backward-selection/

Comment: All mentioned packages did not support sparseMatrix.